# How to change Devise 401 redirect address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have a Rails 3.2.7 app with Devise and I wanna know how do I change the url to which Devise redirects the user on 401 after he tries to access a page he has no access to. This address defaults to `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in` but I wanna change it to point to another action? How do I do that? Do I have to monkey patch Devise into my app? I find this idea very awkward...

I appreciate any help,

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to monkey patch it, unfortunately. You can see a good tutorial on how to do it here: [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated)

Comment: I see. Not that bad but still, not very elegant. But will do the trick. Thanks!